# MIPS32 Determining Length of Input when Adding IEEE 754 Double Precision Numbers

Tags: floating-point, mips, ieee-754, mips32

I am currently working on an assignment to add and multiply IEEE 754 double precision FP numbers in MIPS.

I was able to translate the numbers from IEEE to binary decimal numbers, and then normalize them to have the same exponent, but I am struggling with keeping track of the decimal point after addition (ie 1.XXXX + 1.XXXX = 1X.XXXX and will have to be normalized to  1.XXXXX x 2^1)

My strategy is to determine if the result is longer than either of the two numbers, and then normalize.

I am having trouble with determining the length of the two inputs, since they are stored in two separate registers and could be any length up to 53 bits (X. + first 31 bits of the mantissa in r1, and the lower 21 bits of the mantissa in r2.)

Comment: Minor: "keeping track of the decimal point " --> "keeping track of the _binary_ (or radix) point "

Comment: Suggest posting the code you wrote that you are having trouble with, else this is too  broad a question.